# Signing an XML document is successful but the Digest is incorrect

Tags: java, xml, saml, digital-signature

i need to sign an XML document (more specific, a SAML AuthnRequest) and send to a server Base64 encoded. The problem is that when i try to validate the result, it fails.

Here's the code i use to generate the XML signature:

```
public byte[] sign(Document doc, String signatureMethodName, String digestMethodName, boolean useExclusiveCanonization, boolean effectiveSignDocument) throws XMLSignatureException, MarshalException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        XMLSignatureFactory signatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
        KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = signatureFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
        
        Document deepCopiedDoc = effectiveSignDocument ? null : DocumentLoader.parse(DocumentLoader.stringify(doc, true));
        
        DOMSignContext context = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, effectiveSignDocument ? doc.getDocumentElement() : deepCopiedDoc.getDocumentElement());
        //context.setBaseURI("#" + doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("ID"));
        context.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds");
        
        Reference reference;
        SignedInfo signedInfo;
        try {
            DigestMethod digestMethod = signatureFactory.newDigestMethod(digestMethodName, null);
            SignatureMethod signatureMethod = signatureFactory.newSignatureMethod(signatureMethodName, null);
            String canonization = useExclusiveCanonization ? CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE : CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE;

            List<Transform> transforms = Arrays.asList(
                    signatureFactory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null),
                    signatureFactory.newTransform(canonization, (TransformParameterSpec) null)
            );

            reference = signatureFactory.newReference("", digestMethod, transforms, null, null);
            
            signedInfo = signatureFactory
                .newSignedInfo(
                    signatureFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(canonization, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                    signatureMethod,
                    Collections.singletonList(reference)
                );
            
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        
        List<X509Data> data = List.of(keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(List.of(certificate)));
        KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(data);
                
        XMLSignature signature = signatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo);
        signature.sign(context);
        
        String signatureValue;
        if(effectiveSignDocument) {
            //NodeList signatureElement = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
            //doc.getDocumentElement().insertBefore(signatureElement.item(0), doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild());

            signatureValue = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:SignatureValue").item(0).getTextContent();
        } else {
            signatureValue = deepCopiedDoc.getElementsByTagName("ds:SignatureValue").item(0).getTextContent();
        }
        
        signatureValue = signatureValue
                .replace("\n", "")
                .replace(" ", "")
                .replace("\r", "");
        
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(signatureValue);
    }
```

And, on the other side:

```
authnRequestDom = fromJaxbToDom(authnRequest);
            //authnRequestDom.normalizeDocument();

            xmlSigner.sign(
                authnRequestDom,
                SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256,
                DigestMethod.SHA256,
                true,
                true
            );
            
            String samlRequest = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(DocumentLoader.stringify(authnRequestDom, true, true).getBytes());

            return new LoginSAMLRequest(authnRequest.getDestination(), samlRequest, relayState);
```

Thanks in advance to everybody

I tried using inclusive canonicalization, changing the digest and sign method, and changing the transform list, but the result is still signed incorrectly

EDIT:
I used two different tools online for validate XML signatures ([this](https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml) and [this](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig-verifier.html)) and both reports me and invalid signature. So the problem is sign side and not validation side

EDIT 2:
DocumentLoader.stringify method:

```
public static String stringify(Document doc, boolean minified, boolean headerIsPresent) throws TransformerException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

    if (!headerIsPresent) {
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    }

    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Use an online checker to see if the signature is correct.   Need to find out if the XML is correctly signed or error is during validation.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, i used two differents online checkers and both reports a signature error

Comment: Why are you replacing the return characters and spaces after you generate the signature?  That is going to change the data and cause the signature to fail.

Comment: Because the method just return the signature value (that i receive formatted and Base64 encoded, and i need to use it as a byte array) and not the document itself. The convertion to string is executed on the second sketch using util `DocumentLoader.stringify()`.

Comment: Let concentrate on the generating the xml, not the validation.  Lets get the function sign working properly.  The function does not need to replace the spaces and returns.  You can convert the Base64 string to bytes without changing any characters.